# How to serialize 'PyIDispatch' object

Tags: python-3.x, serialization, pickle, dill

I want to store an object of my python class in a file so that it can be reused. This class has members of 'PyIDispatch' object. I tried to serialize using JSON, Pickle and, dill, none of them worked.

```
obj_name = ica_api_wrapper.IcaApi(config, close_on_exit=False)
with open('data_file.pkl', 'wb') as file:
        dill.dump(inca_api_o, file)
```

This throws the error:
TypeError: cannot pickle 'PyIDispatch' object

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)